# UITableView, UITableViewCell contents disappear on device rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a UITableView programatically using the following code

```
[self createUITableView:categoryTableView
                  frame:CGRectMake(0, [UIApplication currentSize].height - ([UIApplication currentSize].height*0.2) - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20, [UIApplication currentSize].width,[UIApplication currentSize].height * 0.2)
                    tag:1
               rotation:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)];

-(void)createUITableView :(UITableView*)tableView frame:(CGRect)frame tag:(NSInteger)tag rotation:(CGAffineTransform)rotation
{
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableView.transform = rotation;
    tableView.frame = frame;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    tableView.tag = tag;
    tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    tableView.bounces = false;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

After rotating the Tableview i will then rotate the cell for the contents to be displayed the correct way

```
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthforTableView,tableView.frame.size.height )];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];
            cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
            //cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            cellImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        }
```

when i rotate the device i resize the UItableview and change the position to fit nicely on the screen, i also resize the tableview row height and call tableview reloadData

however due to the tableviews resize i find the the contents of the tableview cells disappear.

cell.textlabel disappears and also any other custom views added.

it seems to only affect the tableview once the cells are rotated using MPI???

so my question is:-

How does one prevent the cells contents from disappearing when you resize/rotate the containing tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Set your cell's contentView frame to the cell bounds, then set it's autoresizingMasks to flexibleHeight and flexibleWidth.

Comment: Thanks stefan for your response, i tried    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
                cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
                cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; but still have the same issue

Comment: Oh wait, are you manually transforming all your interface elements upon device orientation changes ?

Comment: no i am manually transforming the cells and uitableview to produce an horizontal tableview. i found by subclassing the cell and manually transforming the labels etc seemed to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing the tableviewcell and making the transformation rotation within the subclass seemed to resolve this issue.